# Nutritional Information Database

Tags: iphone

I'm working on a nutrition related iPhone application. Similar apps in the App Store have a built-in nutritional information database full of ready to use data. Where can I get my hands on a database like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[nutridb](http://nutridb.org/) has a [download](http://nutridb.org/download.php) available which includes a SQL backup of their database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with maintaining your own database is that it gets out of date very quickly.

There are a number of Nutrition APIs out there:

- http://www.nutritionix.com/api (includes barcodes, around 300K items)
- http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/ (unknown # items)